# Creating an Excel From the sql server data

Tags: excel, azure-logic-apps

I am working on creating a logic app for migrating the sql server data.
I have already written a stored procedure and connected to that particular database.
Written a scheduler logic app which runs every 1 day.
The data from the stored procedure returns me two result sets.
Now I have to use these result sets and create a excel document from the data.
I am unable to find any appropriate action which can does the same.

Also I have to create 2 different workbook sheets 1 each for the result set in the same excel document.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: What format your data get from sql? I don't have right to use Excel Online connector so i just create the csv table with sql data, It worked. Maybe you could have a try with Excel Online connector or create csv table.

Comment: @GeorgeChen the data received from the sql sp is in json format. I have tried converting the json data to csv which I am able to do but I am still struggling with creating a new sheet in the csv file for the second result set. Is it possible from the logic app to achieve it ?

Comment: When you create you csv table you could combine two sets together.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I do that. I searched for combining these 2 csv tables but could not find. These 2 result sets are of different structure. I want these to be in 2 different sheets.